# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin cache issue

Tags: apache, caching, cors

It is a problem about multi-domain access the same server file in chrome.

=========

server: apache (supports **CORS**)

file url: www.a.com/a.file

multi-domain: b.com,c.com …

=========

situation: (in chrome)

1. **b.com** access a.file : **success** .

   and then **c.com** access a.file : **fail**
2. **b.com** access a.file : success .

   and then **clean cache of chrome**,

   and **c.com** access a.file : **success**
3. **b.com** access a.file with **http** : **success** .

   and then **b.com** access a.file with **https** : **fail** (like 1)
4. **b.com** access a.file with **http** : **success** .

   and then **clean cache** of chrome,

   and **b.com** access a.file with **https** : **fail** (like 2)

In situation 1,here is the request header. and I notice that the request will access file from cache , and **both Access-Control-Allow-Origin are http://www.b.com**. maybe it is the key of this problem. But I have no idea…

b.com

```
Request URL:www.a.com/a.file
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache) <-here

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.b.com <--(here! the same as situation 2)
Content-Length:115
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Wed, 04 Nov 2015 10:21:29 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 28 Jul 2015 01:41:20 GMT
Server:Apache
```

c.com

```
Request URL:www.a.com/a.file
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache) <-here

Response Headers
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.b.com <--(here! it is "http://www.a.com" in situation 2)
Content-Length:115
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Wed, 04 Nov 2015 10:21:29 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 28 Jul 2015 01:41:40 GMT
Server:Apache
```

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved.

Just need to add **Header append Vary Origin** to httpd.conf in Apache.

[here](https://www.fastly.com/blog/varnish-tip-caching-with-cors) is the detail.

Comment: Did you add this to the conf on `a.com` `b.com` or `c.com`?

Comment: on a.com, which the file belongs to.

Comment: Thanks! Needed to check this with something I was doing :)